# How do I optimize and loop through a 2D list with at least 1000 objects

Tags: java

I currently have 2d list where specific data will be selected depending on the date.  I have a method where it looks at the dates, and if true, it will append the rows to another list. Currently, since the main list holds about 1000 objects, my code is running slow, and I cant seem to find a way to optimize the results.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;

import customAdapters.Fixtures;


public class temp {

Fixtures fixtures = new Fixtures(); 
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
ArrayList<Date> team_fix_date = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> betWeek = new ArrayList<>();
public List<List<String>> gamesTwo = new ArrayList<>();


public void matchesByDate(){


    for (int i = 0; i < fixtures.allLeagues.size(); i++) {

        String week = fixtures.allLeagues.get(i).get(3);

        try {

            Date date = formatter.parse(week);

            team_fix_date.add(date);


        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

public void dayTwo() {

    matchesByDate();

    Date date = new Date();
    Date today = new Date(date.getDay()-1);
    Date date_5;
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    cal2.clear(Calendar.AM_PM);
    cal2.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    cal2.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    cal2.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    cal2.setTime(date);
    cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);



    ArrayList<Date> dateMatches = team_fix_date;


    date_5 = cal2.getTime();



    for (Date date_matches: dateMatches) {
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        if (date_matches.after(today) && date_matches.before(date_5)) {
            betWeek.add(ft.format(date_matches));
            betWeek = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(betWeek));
        }

    }

}

public List<String> weekMatches(int x) {

    dayTwo();


    for( String dates: betWeek) {
        if (dates.equals(fixtures.allLeagues.get(x).get(3)))

            return fixtures.allLeagues.get(x);
    }
    return null;

}

public void addMatchesByDateTwo(){

    for (int x = 0; x < fixtures.allLeagues.size(); x++) {

        if (weekMatches(x) != null)
            gamesTwo.add(Arrays.asList(weekMatches(x).get(0), weekMatches   (x).get(1),
                    weekMatches(x).get(2)));

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: show us the code for the `Fixtures` class; in particular, show us what type `allLeagues` is

Comment: added the fixtures class @willywonkadailyblah thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is really really awful. Why do you add four 'property values' to a list, instead of creating a class with four properties, like OOP should be done?
This might also prevent the time-intense string-to-date conversions taht you call each and every time.

Why do you not stick to naming conventions, like Uppercase class names?

´if (weekMatches(x) != null) gamesTwo.add(Arrays.asList(weekMatches(x).get(0), weekMatches(x).get(1), weekMatches(x).get(2)));´ is your basic problem. You recall and recall and recall all the list filtering process. save it in a variable!

Use for-each loops to make code more readable.

În every weekMatches() call you extend the team_fix_date by all game dates... HUGE LIST.
This should be done ONCE, in the CTOR.

And theres so much more so much WRONG with that code, I'll stop right here.
Left to be said that you really really should get a grip of what you cant to accomplish.

I refactored that code into the following. Try it out:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;



public class InefficientDateShit {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException {
        new Temp();
    }
}



class Temp {
    static public final SimpleDateFormat    formatter       = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

    private final Fixtures                  fixtures;
    private final HashSet<Date>             team_fix_date   = new HashSet<>();
    private final HashSet<Date>             betWeek         = new HashSet<>();
    private final List<Game>                gamesTwo        = new ArrayList<>();


    public Temp() throws ParseException {
        fixtures = new Fixtures();

        // former matchesByDate()
        for (final Game game : fixtures.allLeagues) {
            team_fix_date.add(game.getDate());
        }

        // former dayTwo()
        final Date date = new Date();
        final Date today = new Date(date.getDay() - 1);
        Date date_5;
        final Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        cal2.clear(Calendar.AM_PM);
        cal2.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
        cal2.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
        cal2.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
        cal2.setTime(date);
        cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);
        date_5 = cal2.getTime();
        for (final Date date_matches : team_fix_date) {
            if (date_matches.after(today) && date_matches.before(date_5)) {
                betWeek.add(date_matches);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addMatchesByDateTwo() {
        for (final Game game : fixtures.allLeagues) {
            final boolean matches = betWeek.contains(game.getDate()); // formerly done by weekMatches()
            if (matches) gamesTwo.add(game);
        }
    }
}



class Game {
    private final String    mLeague;
    private final String    mTeam1;
    private final String    mTeam2;
    private final Date      mDate;

    public Game(final String pLeague, final String pTeam1, final String pTeam2, final Date pDate) {
        mLeague = pLeague;
        mTeam1 = pTeam1;
        mTeam2 = pTeam2;
        mDate = pDate;
    }

    public String getLeague() {
        return mLeague;
    }
    public String getTeam1() {
        return mTeam1;
    }
    public String getTeam2() {
        return mTeam2;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return mDate;
    }
}



class Fixtures {
    public List<Game> allLeagues = new ArrayList<>();

    public Fixtures() throws ParseException {
        initFixtureBPL();
    }

    private void initFixtureBPL() throws ParseException {
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Flamengo", "Atletico-PR", "2016/08/06");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "America-MG", "Santos", "2016/08/07");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Figueirense", "Sport Recife", "2016/08/07");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Coritiba", "Ponte Preta", "2016/08/07");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Palmeiras", "Vitoria", "2016/08/07");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Internacional", " Fluminense", "2016/08/07");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Santa Cruz", "Sao Paulo", "2016/08/07");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Botafogo", "Gremio", "2016/08/07");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Atletico-MG", "Chapecoense-SC", "2016/08/07");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Corinthians", "Cruzeiro", "2016/08/07");

        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Vitoria", "Santa Cruz", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Ponte Preta", "Figueirense", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Sport Recife", "Flamengo", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Fluminense", "America-MG", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Gremio", "Corinthians", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Cruzeiro", " Coritiba", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Santos", "Atletico-MG", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Sao Paulo", "Botafogo", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Atletico-PR", "Palmeiras", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Chapecoense-SC", "Internacional", "2016/08/15");

        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Corinthians", "Vitoria", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "America-MG", "Chapecoense-SC", "2016/08/19");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Botafogo", "Sport Recife", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Atletico-MG", "Atletico-PR", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Flamengo", "Gremio", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Internacional", "Sao Paulo", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Palmeiras", "Ponte Preta", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Santa Cruz", "Fluminense", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Figueirense", "Cruzeiro", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", "Coritiba", "Santos", "2016/08/22");

        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "Cobresal", "S. Wanderers", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "O'Higgins ", "U. Catolica", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "Palestino", "Huachipato", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "U. De Chile", "Antofagasta", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "Palestino", "Huachipato", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "U. Espanola", "U. De Concepcion", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "Deportes Temuco", "Deportes Iquique", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "A. Italiano", "Colo Colo", "2016/08/08");

        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "Antofagasta", "Cobresal", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "Colo Colo", "Deportes Temuco", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "Deportes Iquique", "O'Higgins", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "Huachipato", "U. Espanola", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "S. Wanderers", "A. Italiano", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "San Luis", "U. De Chile", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "U. Catolica", "Palestino", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "U. De Concepcion", "Everton", "2016/08/14");

        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "A. Italiano", "Antofagasta", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "Cobresal", "Deportes Iquique", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "Everton", "U. Espanola", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "Huachipato", "Colo Colo", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "O'Higgins", "Deportes Temuco", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "Palestino", "San luis", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "U. Catolica", "S. Wanderers", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION CHILE", "U. De Chile", "U. De Concepcion", "2016/08/21");

        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "U. Catolica", "Emelec", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "Barcelona SC", "Mushuc Runa", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "Dep. Cuenca", " Aucas", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "Delfin", "River Ecuador", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "Ind. del Valle", "Fuerza A.", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "LDU Quito", "El Nacional", "2016/08/08");

        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "Mushuc Runa", "Dep. Cuenca", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "River Ecuador", "LDU Quito", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "El Nacional", "Aucas", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "Ind. del Valle", "U. Catolica", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "Emelec", "Barcelona SC", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "Fuerza A.", " Delfin", "2016/08/14");

        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "Aucas", "Mushuc Runa", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "Barcelona SC", "Fuerza A.", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "Delfin", "Ind. del Valle", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "Dep. Cuenca", "River Ecuador", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "LDU Quito", "Emelec", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("ECUADOR SERIE A", "U. Católica", "El Nacional", "2016/08/21");

        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Atl. Venezuela", "Aragua", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Dep. Anzoategui", "Estudiantes Caracas", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "JBL Zulia", "Lara", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Portuguesa", "Estudiantes M.", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Dep. Petare", "Mineros", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Monagas", "Llaneros", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Trujillanos", "La Guaira", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Urenna", "Caracas", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Carabobo", "Dep. Tachira", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Zamora", "Zulia", "2016/08/08");

        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "La Guaira", "Atl. Venezuela", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Aragua", "Urena", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Llaneros", "Dep. Petare", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Zulia", "Trujillanos", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Estudiantes Caracas", "JBL Zulia", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Dep. Tachira", "Dep. Anzoategui", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Caracas", "Monagas", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Lara", "Estudiantes M.", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Mineros", "Carabobo", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Zamora", "Portuguesa", "2016/08/14");

        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "JBL Zulia", "Dep. Tachira", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Portuguesa", "Lara", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Atl. Venezuela", "Zulia", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Monagas", "Aragua", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Trujillanos", "Zamora", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Carabobo", " Llaneros", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Dep. Anzoategui", "Mineros", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Dep. Petare", "Caracas", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Estudiantes de meridas", "Estudiantes Caracas", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("PRIMERA DIVISION VENEZUELA", "Ureña", "La Guaira", "2016/08/21");

        addGame("LIGA MX", "Veracruz", "America", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Cruz Azul", "Tijuana", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Morelia", "Atlas", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "UANL.", "Chiapas", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Leon", "Monterrey", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Guadalajara", "Queretaro", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Necaxa", "UNAM.", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Toluca", "Pachuca", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Puebla", "Santos Laguna", "2016/08/08");

        addGame("LIGA MX", "Tijuana", "Leon", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Queretaro ", "Cruz Azul", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Atlas   ", "Puebla", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Monterrey", "Necaxa", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Pachuca", "UNAM", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "America", " Morelia", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Toluca", "UANL", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Chiapas", "Veracruz", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Santos Laguna", "Guadalajara", "2016/08/14");

        addGame("LIGA MX", "Veracruz", "Toluca", "2016/07/21");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Chiapas", "Morelia", "2016/07/21");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Cruz Azul", "santos laguna.", "2016/07/21");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Guadalajara", "Atlas", "2016/07/21");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "UANL", "Pachuca", "2016/07/21");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Leon", "Queretaro", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Necaxa", "Tijuana", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "UNAM", "Monterrey", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("LIGA MX", "Puebla", "America", "2016/08/21");

        addGame("MLS", "DC United", "Philadelphia Union", "2016/08/07");
        addGame("MLS", "Montreal Impact", "Houston Dynamo", "2016/08/07");
        addGame("MLS", "Toronto FC", "New England Revolution", "2016/08/07");
        addGame("MLS", "Colorado Rapids", "Vancouver Whitecaps", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("MLS", "Real Salt Lake", "Chicago Fire", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("MLS", "Portland Timbers", "Sporting Kansas City", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("MLS", "Orlando City", "Seattle Sounders", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("MLS", "Los Angeles Galaxy", "New York Red Bulls", "2016/08/08");

        addGame("MLS", "DC United", "Portland Timbers", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("MLS", "New York Red Bulls", "Montreal Impact", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("MLS", "Columbus Crew", "New York City", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("MLS", "New England Revolution", "Philadelphia Union", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("MLS", "FC Dallas", " Sporting Kansas City", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("MLS", "Houston Dynamo", "Toronto FC", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("MLS", "Los Angeles Galaxy", "Colorado Rapids", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("MLS", "Chicago Fire", "Orlando City", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("MLS", "Seattle Sounders", "Real Salt Lake", "2016/08/14");

        addGame("MLS", "New York City", "Los Angeles Galaxy", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("MLS", "Philadelphia Union", "Toronto FC    ", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("MLS", "Montreal Impact", "Chicago Fire", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("MLS", "New England Revolution", "Columbus Crew", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("MLS", "Colorado Rapids", "Orlando City ", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("MLS", "Real Salt Lake", "FC Dallas", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("MLS", "Sporting Kansas City", "Vancouver Whitecaps", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("MLS", "DC United", "New York Red Bulls", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("MLS", "Seattle Sounders", "Portland Timbers", "2016/08/21");

        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Kashima", "Vegalta Sendai", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Urawa", "Shonan", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Albirex Niigata", "Kobe", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "G-Osaka", "Tosu", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Hiroshima", "Nagoya", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Kashiwa", "Yokohama M.", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Kawasaki", "Kofu", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Omiya Ardija", "Avispa Fukuoka", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Tokyo", "Iwata", "2016/08/08");

        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Kofu", "Albirex Niigata", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Nagoya", "Urawa", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Shonan", "Hiroshima", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Iwata", "G-Osaka", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Kobe   ", "Tokyo", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Tosu", "Kawasaki ", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Vegalta Sendai", "Kashiwa", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Yokohama M.", "Omiya Ardija", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Avispa Fukuoka", "Kashima", "2016/08/14");

        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Kashima", "Shonan", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Omiya Ardija", "Vegalta Sendai", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Albirex Niigata", "Avispa Fukuoka", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "G-Osaka", "kobe", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Hiroshima  ", "Kofu", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Iwata", "Tosu", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Kashiwa", "Nagoya", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Tokyo", "Yokohama M.", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("J-LEAGUE", "Urawa", "Kawasaki", "2016/08/20");

        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Beijing Guoan", "Chongqing Lifan", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Yanbian", "Shanghai SIPG", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Hangzhou Greentown", "Henan Construction", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Shanghai Shenhua", "Guangzhou", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Shijiazhuang", "Tianjin Teda", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Changchun Yatai", "Jiangsu Suning", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Guangzhou R&F", "Shandong Luneng", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Hebei", "Liaoning", "2016/08/08");

        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Guangzhou", "Hangzhou Greentown", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Shanghai SIPG ", "Shijiazhuang", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Shanghai Shenhua", "Liaoning", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Tianjin Teda", "Shandong Luneng", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Changchun Yatai", "Yanbian", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Chongqing Lifan", "Guangzhou R&F", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Henan Construction", "Hebei", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Jiangsu Suning", "Beijing Guoan", "2016/08/14");

        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Chongqing Lifan", "Yanbian", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Liaoning", "Hangzhou Greentown", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Hebei", "Guangzhou", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Shandong Luneng", "Changchun Yatai", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Shanghai SIPG", "Beijing Guoan", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Tianjin Teda", " Henan Construction", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Guangzhou R&F", "Shangai Shenhua", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("SUPERLIGA CHINA", "Shijiazhuang", "Jiangsu Suning", "2016/08/21");

        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Odense", "Viborg", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Nordsjaelland", "Aalborg", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Sonderjyske", "FC Copenhague", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Midtjylland", "Brondby", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Esbjerg", "Aarhus", "2016/08/08");

        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Viborg", "Randers", "2016/08/12");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Lyngby", "Aarhus", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Horsens", "Silkeborg", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "FC Copenhague", "Midtjylland", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Odense", "Nordsjaelland", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Brondby", "Sonderjyske", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Aalborg", "Esbjerg", "2016/08/15");

        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Nordsjaelland", "Randers", "2016/08/19");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Horsens", "Lyngby", "2016/08/19");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "FC Copenhague", "Aalborg", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Silkeborg", "Viborg", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Aarhus", "Brondby", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Midtjylland", "Sonderjyske", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("DINAMARCA SUPERLIGA", "Esbjerg", "Odense", "2016/08/22");

        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Nijmegen", "Zwolle", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", " Den Haag", "G.A. Eagles", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Twente", "Excelsior", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Utrecht", "PSV", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Willem", "Vitesse", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Groningen", "Feyenoord", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "AZ Alkmaar", "Heerenveen", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Sparta Rotterdam", "Ajax", "2016/08/08");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Roda", "Heracles", "2016/08/08");

        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Heerenveen", "Utrecht", "2016/08/12");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", " Excelsior", "Groningen", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Ajax", "Roda", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Vitesse", "Den Haag", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Zwolle", "Sparta Rotterdam", "2016/08/13");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Heracles", "Willem II", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Feyenoord", "Twente", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "G.A. Eagles", "Nijmegen", "2016/08/14");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "PSV", "AZ Alkmaar", "2016/08/14");

        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Excelsior", "Den Haag", "2016/08/19");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", " Roda", "Vitesse", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Ajax", "Willem II", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Zwolle", "PSV", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Nijmegen", "Heerenveen", "2016/08/20");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Groningen", "Twente", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Sparta Rotterdam", "G.A. Eagles", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Utrecht", "AZ Alkmaar", "2016/08/21");
        addGame("EREDIVISIE", "Heracles", "Feyenoord", "2016/08/21");
    }


    private void addGame(final String pLeague, final String pTeam1, final String pTeam2, final String pDate) throws ParseException {
        final Date date = Temp.formatter.parse(pDate);
        allLeagues.add(new Game(pLeague, pTeam1, pTeam2, date));
    }

}
```

Comment: you are right, that's why I posted this here to find suggestions and learn to be more efficient, ill give this code a try, thanks for helping. @jayC667

Comment: thanks for proving such a detailed answer, this helped a lot. It greatly improved code performance.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the comments of @janos who worked with your existing code, are you tied to the way you are representing the data? Fixing things like how often you create a DateFormatter and unnecessary list creation will speed up your code, the first thing that comes to mind for me is that the data structure is not ideal. You are storing a bunch of strings then doing conversions of strings to dates to do comparisons. Why not just store them as dates in the first place? If you do that, you will need to create some classes for the different values. Also, again not sure if you are using the older java.util.Date for a specific reason (perhaps tied to an older version of java) but if you are able to use Java 8 (and if not, try to be able to... Java 7 and previous are no longer supported) then I highly recommend using the newer date and time objects in the java.time package. The older java.util.Date have a ton of deprecated methods, are dangerous, hard to use properly, and many things are super slow. The newer dates are much, much nicer, based on Joda time and a lot safer as well.

A simple example (though not super optimized because I don't know what else your program needs to do) follows. Please note that I again didn't fully flesh out any of the classes since I didn't know what you needed exactly, but if you followed something like this, I'd recommend you implement the things that make sense (e.g. equals, hashCode, etc) for the classes. Also should probably make the fields private and add getter methods.

```
class Fixtures {
    final List<League> allLeagues = new ArrayList<>();

    Fixtures() {
        List<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();
        games.add(new Game(new Team("Flamengo"), new Team("Atletico-PR"), LocalDate.of(2016, 8, 6)));
        games.add(new Game(new Team("America-MG"), new Team("Santos"), LocalDate.of(2016, 8, 7)));
        allLeagues.add(new League("BRASILEIRAO SERIE A", games));
        // ... etc
    }
}

class League {
    final String name;
    final List<Game> games;

    public League(String name, List<Game> games) {
        this.name = name;
        this.games = new ArrayList<>(games);
    }
}

class Team {
    final String name;

    Team(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Game {
    final Team team1;
    final Team team2;
    final LocalDate date;

    Game(Team team1, Team team2, LocalDate date) {
        this.team1 = team1;
        this.team2 = team2;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: the final outcome is to display the games related to the current week on an expandable listview (this is for an android app). I made the changes to code, and it made it faster, but it is still taking at least 10 min to load, so the performance is horrible. @aarondavis

Comment: This code is also good, related to the answer provided by jay, I will continue to reference this for the future. Thanks again.